# Write before the cursor

Tags: vim, vi

In Vim, I have

```
a #write after cursor
A #write after end line
I #write at start of line
```

I want to write before a word, for example

```
I want to edit this line
```

My cursor is at the position after `this`. I want to write before this without deleting `this`. How?

Comment: Type "bi" with your cursor at the end of "this" ... ?

Comment: bi is good,put as answer i can vote it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

- <kbd>esc</kbd> puts you in normal mode
- <kbd>b</kbd> goes to the beginning of the previous word
- <kbd>i</kbd> puts you in insert mode.